# Regex for string containing no whitespace and at least one '*'

Tags: java, regex

I'm kind of stuck on this one. Examples of strings that should match:

- *abc
- abc*
- *abc*
- ab*c
- a*b*c
- *a*b*c*

Examples of strings that should not match:

- abc
- *
- abc *
- a *bc (in this example '*bc' should match)

(PS: I'm working in Java if that makes a difference)

Comment: What does `*` represent? Any character?

Comment: [`(?:\*[a-z]+|[a-z]+\*)+[*a-z]?`](https://regex101.com/r/eKIBBZ/1)

Comment: not sure how this is "too broad"; some people are just annoyed that you asked for a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern to ensure that there is at least one `*` in the match, and a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that the `*` is not alone:

```
(?=\S*\*)(?!\*(?:\s|$))\S+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0sdl5a/1

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using lookaheads:

`[a-z]+\*[*a-z]*|\*+[a-z][*a-z]*`

first case is where the required letter appears before the first star.

second case is where the star(s) appear first followed by the required letter.

the two cases are combined using `|`